# "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm." Django - new user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a new user for my application by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OhF6FEdIao&t=20s) . I am able to create a new user but the on opening django admin page the password is shown as

> "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."

I have seen similar questions where the answer was to set

> account.set_password(password)

I have tried this but it did not work for me.

**(EDIT: It seems the .save() is not being called from views.py. I am not sure why)**

Here is my code

**Serializer.py**

```
class RegistraionSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password2   =   serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'},read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model   = User
    fields  = ('phone','name','password','password2','user_type','email')

    extra_kwargs    =   {
        'password': {'write_only' : True},


    }
    def save(self):
        print('here')
        account = User(
            phone   =   self.validated_data['phone'],
            email   =   self.validated_data['email']
        )
        
        password    = self.validated_data['password']
        password2    = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            print(password)
            return serializers.ValidationError({'password':'password mismatch'})
        print(password)
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
```

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Registraion(request):
serializer  = RegistraionSerialzer(data=request.data)
data        = {}
print('reg vie')

if serializer.is_valid():
    account             =   serializer.save()
    data['response']    =   "Successfully registered "
    data['name']        =   account.name
    data['password']       =   account.password
    print(data)
else:
    print(serializer.errors)
return Response(data)
```

Comment: The users you already registered will still contain a non-hashed password. You thus should ensure *all* the views where you create a user or update the password use `.set_password`, and make sure that the old users are removed/updated with a new password.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem currently this is the only view where the users are created. i tried manually adding a user through the terminal and that had a password with the proper hashing

Comment: the question is: did you create users *before* altering the logic, that still have a password generated with the *old* logic.

Comment: Just to be sure... There are some errors in your code (like `self.self`, and calling `account.create_user()` which is a method that does not exist on the standard Django User). Have you checked that your registration request works?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I deleted the db and migrations and started afresh with current logic but still facing same issue

Comment: @spottexj  you are right. That is just my "why is this not working" code. i fixed it but issue persists

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class RegistraionSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password2   =   serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'},read_only=True)
class Meta:
model   = User
fields  = ('phone','name','password','password2','user_type','email')

extra_kwargs    =   {
    'password': {'write_only' : True},


}
def save(self):
    print('here')
    account = User(
        phone   =   self.validated_data['phone'],
        email   =   self.validated_data['email']
    )
    
    password    = self.validated_data['password']
    password2    = self.validated_data['password2']
    if password != password2:
        print(password)
        return serializers.ValidationError({'password':'password mismatch'})
    print(password)
    account.set_password(make_password(password))
    account.save()
```